# How can I set delay for running functions

Tags: javascript, function, delayed-execution

I have javascript for call 2 function for example:

```
system.library.myscript.function1();
system.library.myscript.function2();
```

I would like to set delay before run function2 for example 20 seconds. 
Highly appreciated for anything helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTimeout() function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

:)

Comment: Don't use w3schools.com as a reference... Instead use the [Mozilla Developmer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) which also [explains the changing execution context (`this`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem) which can be a problem here

Comment: @Andreas—good comment re w3schools, but note that *this* is one parameter of an execution context, it's not **the** execution context (you can't get a reference to that). ;-)

Comment: @RobG You're right. I only added it because the section in the MDN article is labeled with " _The "this" problem_ "